# CodeIgnite Active Record set method with MySQL function SUBSTRING_INDEX

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my working MySQL query:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `ea_appointments` 
SET `id_services` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, '|', -1), 
`id_users_customer` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, '|', 2), '|', -1), 
`hash` = MD5(`id_google_calendar`) 
WHERE `is_unavailable`= 1 AND `notes` LIKE '%|%'");
```

This is my first attempt at translating it to Codigniter's Activerecord/Query Builder format

```
$this->db->set("id_services","SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, '|', -1)");
$this->db->set("id_users_customer","SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, '|', 2), '|', -1)");
$this->db->set("hash","MD5(id_google_calendar)");
$this->db->where("is_unavailable= 1");
$this->db->where("notes LIKE '%|%'");
$this->db->update("ea_appointments");
```

Does this look correct? The problem is that with this, it is not pulling out the data between the pipes where in MySQL it is.  I am using SUBSTRING_INDEX in MySQL, should I be using a PHP equivalent instead?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Yes and it is not separating out the data between the pipes.  I am not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

When trouble shooting CI queries, make sure that the save_queries option is set in the database settings (at least on dev.) and then use echo $this->db->last_query().  This is a good place to start troubleshooting.

It is likely that the CI escaping is getting you into trouble.  try it setting the escape to FALSE.
for eg.

```
$this->db->set("id_services","SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, '|', -1)",FALSE);
```

You can read about it in the docs [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=active%20record#updating-data).

also, there is an issue with the [where](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) clause this:

```
$this->db->where("is_unavailable= 1");
$this->db->where("notes LIKE '%|%'");
```

should be:

```
$this->db->where("is_unavailable",1)
     ->like('notes','|');
```

If you want to use the single evaluation its best to do something like

```
$this->db->where("is_unavailable= 1",NULL,FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks, setting the escape to FALSE does not do it.  The reason for the pipe delimiter is that Google Calendar does not give us custom fields to save to.  I have some codes that need to be saved with appointments and this was the only work around I could see.  Nevertheless, it works with SQL but not in Active Record format (yet).  I tried using logging of the queries using this http://jigarjain.com/blog/saving-all-db-queries-in-codeigniter/ but I do not see the query logged after it is ran.

Answer (score 0):

Please change to bellow

```
$this->db->set("id_services","SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, '|', -1)", false);
        $this->db->set("id_users_customer","SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, '|', 2), '|', -1)", false);
$this->db->set("hash","MD5(id_google_calendar)", false);
$this->db->where("is_unavailable= 1");
$this->db->where("notes LIKE '%|%'");
$this->db->update("ea_appointments");
```

It will work but i think where should change to

```
$this->db->where("is_unavailable", 1);
$this->db->like("notes", '|', 'both');
```